# Reading with Darkvision

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So with [Darkvision](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Darkvision) you cannot discern color. Recently I stumbled upon a debate fighting over wether or not you could read in darkness with darkvision, since you cannot discern the color of the ink from the color of the page. Some argued that you would only be able to discern the text if it had texture, while others said there was special ink - But some of these arguments drew from 3.0 and 3.5. I was wondering if there were any official rulings one way or the other.

Comment: Can you link to this debate?

Comment: In an attempt to find it again after my game, I found another answer that answers my question. I have flagged my question as duplicate and pointed to that question. Hopefully my question being a little more specific will help future googlers find the answer!